# lambdista - No instance, of the ConcreteValue, compilation errors converting config to custom class

Tags: scala, lambdista-config

While trying to use [lambdista config](https://github.com/lambdista/config)

I receive the following **compilation errors**:

- No instance, of the ConcreteValue type class, found for config.ExampleConfig.FooConfig
- not enough arguments for method as: (implicit evidence$1: com.lambdista.config.ConcreteValue[config.ExampleConfig.FooConfig])scala.util.Try[config.ExampleConfig.FooConfig]. Unspecified value parameter evidence$1.

**Sample code** [copied from here](https://github.com/lambdista/config/blob/master/core/src/test/scala/com/lambdista/config/ConfigSpec.scala):

```
package config

import java.io.InputStream
import java.nio.file.Paths

import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.util.{Failure, Success, Try}

import com.lambdista.config.exception.{
    ConfigSyntaxException, ConversionException, KeyNotFoundException}
import com.lambdista.config._

object ExampleConfig extends App {

val confPath = "src//main//resources//example.conf"
val config: Try[Config] = Config.from(Paths.get(confPath))

case class Greek(alpha: String, beta: Int)

case class FooConfig(
  bar: String, 
  baz: Option[Int], 
  list: List[Int],
  map: Greek,
  mapList: List[Greek], 
  range: Range, 
  duration: Duration,
  missingValue: Option[String]
 )

val fooConfig: Try[FooConfig] = for {
    conf <- config
    result <- conf.as[FooConfig]
  } yield result  
}
```

**build.sbt**:

```
  name := "example"

  version := "1.0"

  scalaVersion := "2.10.5"

  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.lambdista" %% "config" % "0.5.0"
  )

   resolvers += Resolver.mavenLocal
```

**Input file**:

```
  // comment 1
 {
  bar = "hello",
  # comment 2
  baz = 42,
  list = [1, // comment 3
        2, 3],
  map = {
  alpha = "hello",
  beta = 42
  },
  mapList = [
   {
    alpha = "hello",
    beta = 42
   },
  {
    alpha = "world",
    beta = 24
  }
],
 range = 2 to 10 by 2,
 duration = 5 seconds
 }
```

How can I get this working?

Comment: have you seen the example? https://github.com/lambdista/config#loading-a-config-from-typesafe-config

Comment: @pedrorijo91  My example several rows above your link https://github.com/lambdista/config#automatic-conversion-to-a-case-class

Comment: Same error with this example too